# In Rails 5 belongs_to, how do I disregard id and create accociation by unique name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I have a model with this association:

```
belongs_to :nesti_commodity,
  -> { where name: nesti_commodity },
  inverse_of: :commodity_to_products
```

CommodityToProducts has nesti_commodity column, which holds a string.
We do not have nesti_commodity_id.

NestiCommodity has id column and name column. My senior colleague want it to be associated by name column, which is a String and he wants to disregard id.

How do I do it in Rails 5? what is the cleanest way of breaking the conventions in such circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the answer because I needed has_many, through: association.

In the end I have implemented my own method called nesti_commodity_record, and I will use this convention when I need to use non standard associations.

```
def nesti_commodity_record
  NestiCommodity.where(name: nesti_commodity).last
end
```

With regards to has_many, through:, I have implemented own method that uses Arel and joins.

```
# this simulates has_many_through
def nesti_commodity_records
  NestiCommodity.select(
    NestiCommodity.arel_table[Arel.star]
  ).where(
    CommodityToProduct.arel_table[:mrl_product_id].eq(id)
  ).joins(
    NestiCommodity.arel_table.join(CommodityToProduct.arel_table).on(
      NestiCommodity.arel_table[:name]
        .eq(CommodityToProduct.arel_table[:nesti_commodity])
    ).join_sources
  )
end
```